# Firebase - email address is already in use by another account

Tags: java, android

When I try to login in my app with fire base authentication it shows email address is already in use by another account.I can't figure out what is the problem.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText login_email, login_password;
private Button login_button;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}


public void onClickLoginButton(View view) {

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, " Please Wait...", "its processing", true);

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(login_email.getText().toString(), login_password.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfull...Bingo...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("Email", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            });


}
}
```

Comment: `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` will create a new user, it's not for login.
For login, follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password

Answer (score 0):

**firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)** this is used to create new user..

for logging in an existing user you can use **firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)**

for more information follow this firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password